# @FormParam gives null Javascript to REST Jersey

Tags: javascript, java, rest, post, jersey

I am trying to do a POST request/fetch were I want to send some values and after reading around I found out that @FormParam is what I should use but I cant get it to work. I try to do my Fetch as such

```
  createOyster(){
  var resource = "version=" + this.state.version + "&customer=" + this.state.customer + "&userId=" + this.state.userId + "&oysterName=" + this.state.oysterName + "&backupFile=" + this.state.backupFile;
  console.log(resource)
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/sleepy-oyster/v2/oyster/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      resource
    })
  })
}
```

And the console.log(resource) gives

```
version=[object Object]&customer=NCC&userId=johjon&oysterName=NCC_johjon2&backupFile=Kund_NCC_Prod_2018-03-22.228680192.bak
```

And when i try to do the request ot my REST that looks like this

```
 @POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response createOyster(@FormParam("version") String version, @FormParam("customer") String customer,
                             @FormParam("userId") String userId, @FormParam("oysterName") String oysterName,
                             @FormParam("backupFile") String backupFile) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(version + "HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ HEJ");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    NexusResource resource = mapper.readValue(version, NexusResource.class);
    System.out.println(resource);

     dbWorker.restoreDatabase(userId, backupFile);
     oysterWorker.createOyster(userId, oysterName);
     oysterWorker.installOyster(oysterName);
     String selectedVersion = versionWorker.getVersionFromNexus(resource,oysterName,customer);

     return Response.ok(selectedVersion).build();
}
```

I get an NullPointerException that doesn't point to any of my code which makes me confused

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl (WebComponent.java:489)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service (WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service (ServletContainer.java:388)
```

I have probably screwed something up since its my first time using @FormParam. Can anyone see why it gives null. the Sout in my REST gives null as well so the REST does not get it. I guess it is because the version is an [object Object] because the rest does not give null. How would I handle that?

If I just console.log(this.state.version) I get my full object

```
{resourceURI: "http://nexus.ad.hrm.se/nexus/service/local/reposit…ent/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/", relativePath: "/se/hrmsoftware/hrm/hrm-release/16.1-SNAPSHOT/", text: "16.1-SNAPSHOT", leaf: false, lastModified: "2018-05-02 06:57:07.0 UTC", …}
```

Comment: Change "@FormParam" to "@RequestParam" and checked the result

Comment: Stop converting form data to JSON, i.e. just do `body: resource`, as that is what `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` means.

Comment: As for version, try `"version=" + this.state.version.text`

Comment: @Andreas i tried changing to .text it gives in the console.log the first part from the [object Object] but still gives null in the REST print